# Book style used in Concrete Mathematics

Tags: book-design

Does anyone know what style is used in Dr. Knuth's Concrete Mathematics? I'm hoping to use it for my dissertation. I know that they use the concrete and Euler fonts, but with regards Chapter formatting etc. are they using anything other than the standard book style?

Comment: I think I read somewhere that Knuth uses just raw TeX, but can't recall where I read that.

Comment: Related Question: [Has the typesetting of Knuth and gang's Concrete Mathematics been modified over subsequent editions?](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/17835/has-the-typesetting-of-knuth-and-gangs-concrete-mathematics-been-modified-over).

Answer (score 12, accepted):

*Concrete Mathematics* is typeset with plain TeX. The TeX source code of the style is available at CTAN:

http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/plain/contrib/misc/gkpmac.tex

And it is also available in TeX Live and MiKTeX distributions, with Plain TeX package.